# Jquery all checkbox select only works once

Tags: jquery

i looked at other threads but didn't find any solution that will work for me.

I'm trying to select all the checkboxes here HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall" onchange="toggleAllWorkers(this.checked);" />ALL<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="emp" name="w0" value="1" onchange="buildPage();" />Andrey <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="emp" name="w1" value="4" onchange="buildPage();" />Brian <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="emp" name="w2" value="5" onchange="buildPage();" />Eric <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="emp" name="w3" value="3" onchange="buildPage();" />Ken <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="emp" name="w4" value="2" onchange="buildPage();" />Kerry <br>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function toggleAllWorkers(status) {
    $("#clickmenu .emp").each( function(index) {
        console.log( index + ": "+$(this).attr("checked")+' status:'+status+' Value:'+$(this).val());
        $(this).attr("checked",status);
        console.log( index + ": "+$(this).attr("checked"));
    });
}
```

But it only works twice after page reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `prop` function. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
function toggleAllWorkers(status) {
    $('.emp').prop('checked',status);
}
```

As well, there is no need to use the `each`, this can be done with one simple selector.

Comment: when i'm trying to get values they all happend to be "on" all the time.   var values = {};
 $inputs.each(function() {
  values[this.name] = $(this).val();
 });

Comment: It doesnt work neither way. if i put console.log(values); it returns all checkboxes 'on'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nvqBA/ - I'm not sure why you are seeing that, take a look at this

Answer (score 3):

replace all instances of `attr()` :

```
$(this).attr("checked",status);
```

with `prop()` :

```
$(this).prop("checked",status);
```

when you're changing a property like `checked`.
You could remove the inline js and shorten the event handler down to :

```
$('#selectall').on('change', function() {
    $("#clickmenu .emp").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: I'ts because attr() changes the attribute only, and the next time the function runs, it checks if the property is set, which it isn't as it wasn't changed, only the attribute was.

Comment: Could also just do `this.checked = status;`